# maximum no of sockets on serversocket

Tags: java, sockets

I was looking at the serversocket API and it said maximum no of allowed connections is 50. I tried testing it..

```
public class ClientSocketTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        int count = 10000;
        Socket[] clients = new Socket[count];
        for(int i = 0; i < count ; i++)
        {
            clients[i] = new Socket("localhost", 9090);
            System.out.println("connected to server: " + i);
        }


     }
    }

    public class ServerSocketTest {

        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
        {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9090);
            int i =1;

        while(true){
            serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Accepted port" + i++);
        }


    }

}
```

I started of with count value of 50 in the clientsockettest program. I was able to increase it to 10000 and still get the program to run without any errors.

What is the maximum no of connections allowed?

Comment: Are you talking about `java.net.ServerSocket`? I looked through the API docs and don't see anything about a maximum allowed connections.

Comment: I think it depends from your system/platform.
Java is absolutely a *net* language, so java supports big systems.
Java takes the maximum ports and connection ability from your system and makes the connections.If your system can't have all these, the other connections fails.
i tried above program in my system i can go upto 16000 socket connections..
This is the way you can destroy a server...   

But, keep in mind that there is difficult to handle all these connections.You need code to handle connections that are not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was looking at the serversocket API and it said maximum no of allowed connections is 50.

No it didn't. It said the *default backlog* is 50. Completely different thing.

There is no maximum imposed by Java. There is an operating system limit on file descriptors or socket buffer space (Windows), but you are just as likely to run out of threads or thread stack space as to hit this.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on Operating system and not programming language

Comment: It doesn't depend on the network driver. It depends on he operating system and available memory.